# Using Clear Case remote client with egit

Tags: git, egit, clearcase-remote-client

The version control I am using is Clear Case Remote Client for eclipse. I need to have a useful diff functionality. I searched through net and found external diff tools like KDiff3 , BeyondCompare but didnt find clear instructions to install them on Mac. I read somewhere best option is to use git with CCRC. Can someone please explain how can I use Clear Case Remote client with egit to get diff functionality? I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use Egit here.
You can change the diff manager in CCRC in order to call any diff tool you want:
See "[Changing the Diff/merge Type Manager in CCRC 7.1.1 and later](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21433959)"

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21433959&aid=2]

As mentioned in "[How to Use Kdiff3 as a 3-way Merge Tool With Mercurial, Git, and Tower.app](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/12/how-to-use-kdiff3-as-a-3-way-merge-tool-with-mercurial-git-and-tower-app)":

> Installing `kdiff3` is as easy as downloading the latest version from sourceforge and copying it to your `/Applications` directory.
>
> The app is a simple wrapper around a Qt-based application.
> It can be run from the command line at `/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3`.